# Snowflake AAD OAuth2 (EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_CANT_RETRIEVE_PUBLIC_KEY)

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We've configured Snowflake for Oauth2 using AAD when we retrieve a token the audience, scope, ... are correct.

But when validating using `SYSTEM$VERIFY_EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN`

we receive the following error (and no information can be found why this is occuring)

> Token Validation finished.{"Validation Result":"Failed","Failure
> Reason":"EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_CANT_RETRIEVE_PUBLIC_KEY"}

Has anyone had this error before?

Answer (score 1):

Create the security integration using the public key as a single line:

```
EXTERNAL_OAUTH_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY=MIIBIjANBgk......IDAQAB
```

Make sure you also remove from the public key the `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely while creating the security integration,value for Public Key was not extracted from the IdP's certificate and instead, the certificate was entered.

Comment: Thanks Srinath.We have tried on the Enterprise SF and AAD tenant and also on a dev (open) SF and AAD. Same issue occurs for both.

Comment: Can you provide the security object create statement?

Comment: This issue can happen only if the external_oauth_jws_keys_url value is incorrect. Are you sure the url used is correct?

Comment: when a EXTERNAL_OAUTH_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY is configured then the external_oauth_jws_keys_url can't also be set. If you attempt to set it you'll see - SQL execution error: JWS Key URL and RSA Public Keys cannot be set simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SECURITY INTEGRATION jwt_rsa_aaa
    TYPE = EXTERNAL_OAUTH
    ENABLED = TRUE
    EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TYPE = CUSTOM 
    EXTERNAL_OAUTH_ISSUER = 'AAAA'
    EXTERNAL_OAUTH_AUDIENCE_LIST = ('a', 'b')
    EXTERNAL_OAUTH_SCOPE_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE = 'scp'
    EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN_USER_MAPPING_CLAIM = ('sub', 'snowflake_{0}')
    EXTERNAL_OAUTH_SNOWFLAKE_USER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE = LOGIN_NAME
    EXTERNAL_OAUTH_ANY_ROLE_MODE = ENABLE
    EXTERNAL_OAUTH_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==';
```

However when attempting to use a JWT, and confirmed the public key is valid etc. We keep seeing the following error

```
Token Validation finished.{"Validation Result":"Failed","Failure Reason":"EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_CANT_RETRIEVE_PUBLIC_KEY"}
```

The documentation shows the JWS url is optional. When we provide a dummy value - then we can not longer create the security integration as it'll mention that the JWS url and the RSA public key can't both be provided.

Comment: Can you try creating the security integration using `EXTERNAL_OAUTH_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY=MIIBIjANBgk......IDAQAB` in this form and as a single line key? Just copy the public key, remove the `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` and make it a single line before pasting it into EXTERNAL_OAUTH_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY.

Comment: Ha, that worked! If you want, put in an answer - and I'm happy to give you the credit/bounty.